# How do I perform a JOIN if one of multiple conditions is true?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My end goal...`SELECT` all fields from `qry1` on rows where either the home phone, cell phone, OR work phone match `tbl2`

This is my current SQL syntax that's "failing." By failing I mean it hasn't finished executing after 10-15 minutes while the individual joins each (independently) run in a minute or two a piece.

`SELECT qry1.*
 FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2
   ON ((qry1.CellPhone = tbl2.CellPhone)
   OR (qry1.HomePhone = tbl2.HomePhone)
   OR (qry1.WorkPhone = tbl2.WorkPhone));`

Questions:
Are there errors in my SQL syntax?
Is there a better way to complete my task?
Would it make more sense for me to simply run the 3 (Home, work, cell) JOIN queries independently, UNION them, and then dedupe if necessary?

Comment: There aren't errors in your SQL syntax; the query wouldn't run if there were.  How big, roughly, are the tables?  How many rows in each, and a typical row size.  And roughly how many rows are there in the result set?  That's mostly curiosity — but 1-2 minutes per separate query suggests that the tables must be quite large.

Comment: In Excel (xlsx format) the larger table feeding qry1 is 80 MB, tbl2 is 50 MB. tbl2 is hideously wide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the individual joins work fast, the composite OR condition is probably slow because it cannot use a single index whereas the individual conditions can each use a single index for the three joining conditions. Because it can't use one index, it is probably doing non-indexed sequential table scans. (You should study the query plan so you understand what the optimizer is actually doing.)

Given that the individual queries work reasonably fast, therefore, you should get dramatically better performance using UNION (unless the optimizer in your DBMS has a blind spot):

```
SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON qry1.CellPhone = tbl2.CellPhone
UNION
SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON qry1.HomePhone = tbl2.HomePhone
UNION
SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON qry1.WorkPhone = tbl2.WorkPhone
```

That should give you a result approximately as quickly as the 3 individual queries.  It won't be quite as fast because UNION does duplicate elimination (which the individual queries do not, of course).  You could use UNION ALL, but if there are many rows in the two tables where 2 or 3 of the pairs of fields match, that could lead to a lot of repetition in the results.

Comment: I'd also like to add that your use of `UNION` for duplicate elimination was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

`or` can be rather difficult for SQL optimizers.  I would suggest 3 indexes and the folllowing query:

```
SELECT qry1.*
FROM qry1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 WHERE qry1.CellPhone = tbl2.CellPhone) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 WHERE qry1.HomePhone = tbl2.HomePhone) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 WHERE qry1.WorkPhone = tbl2.WorkPhone);
```

The three indexes are `tbl2(CellPhone)`, `tbl2(HomePhone)`, and `tbl2(WorkPhone)`.

Comment: I think `SELECT NULL ...` is lighter than other dummy `SELECT`-s. In the past I used `SELECT *` for EXISTS subqueries but then seen some examples with `NULL`. Not sure whether my way is better...

Comment: This code was slow BECAUSE I had not created proper indexes. My fault.

Comment: @i486: Any part-way decent query optimizer ignores the select list in an EXISTS sub-query; it doesn't matter whether you write `*`, `1`, `NULL`, or anything else.

Comment: @i486 . . . To further Jonathan's point, some SQL engines will even accept something like `1/0` as the thing being selected.

Answer (score 1):

If this is essentially a self join, where the same people exist in both tbl1 and qry1, then you will probably not be interested where people match themselves, as well as duplicate permutations of the results.  What I mean, is self joins usually have two records where Bob and Jane have the same phone number, and thus your result has joined records of:

```
Bob, Jane
Jane, Bob
Jane, Jane
Bob, Bob
```

Out of those you probably only need `Bob, Jane` since it tells you that those two people have a matching phone number.  **If you have some unique ID then adding `where qry1.SSN < tbl2.SNN` will eliminate many of these duplicates and reduce your result set.  Preferably this column would have an index.**

Comment: In this particular situation your answer/comment didn't really apply, but I know that I'll run into something very similar to this in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696729/4350148 but uses disjoint union. May be more efficient

```
 SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON qry1.CellPhone = tbl2.CellPhone
 UNION distinct
 SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON  
    qry1.CellPhone != tbl2.CellPhone 
    and qry1.HomePhone = tbl2.HomePhone
 UNION distinct
 SELECT qry1.* FROM qry1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON 
    qry1.CellPhone != tbl2.CellPhone 
    and qry1.HomePhone != tbl2.HomePhone
    and qry1.WorkPhone = tbl2.WorkPhone
```